# Combining string with texbox value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have Access application in which I have database of serial numbers. I am searching through my database of serial numbers using this command: `Like [Forms]![frm_TEST]![Text5] & "*"`.

Every serial number starts with an `*` and then it is followed by number and letters. 
Everything is working fine but I would like to predefine that star into command so I or user doesn't have to enter this `*`

Something like this: `Like [Forms]![frm_TEST]! "*" & [Text5] & "*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using,

```
Like "[*]" & [Forms]![frm_TEST]![Text5] & "*"
```

To explicitly use the common wildcard character you are supposed to enclose them in square brackets.